# fancybox content appears bottom of my page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have some div's with images in them, and when clicked on I want to load another .php page with fancybox.  The content is loaded, but its just appended to the end of the page.  anyone ever have this problem?

my html:

```
<div id="clickme">
  <img src="someimg.jpg" />
</div>
```

here is my script:

```
$('#clickme').live('click', function(){
  $(this).fancybox({ 'href': 'somefile.php' });
});
```

Comment: Are you including the fancybox CSS file on your page?

Comment: yes, and all the images are in a different directory, but i changed all the links in the css file

Comment: Check your #fancybox-wrap selector in the fancybox css file and make sure it has position:absolute.

Answer (score 1):

i was originally seperating out the css, images and js into my own seperate folders and it wasnt working.  if i just copy the fancybox folder and use everything from there it works

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by ensuring you have this at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional / / EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd ">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Try "View source" on your page after loading it in your browser, the first line should be the doctype line.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of going and coming, I found an answer from the owner of fancybox, please check the thread if you wish: https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/issues/66

The real solution IS NOT to add the `<!DOCTYPE html>` directive, instead wrap the whole content into a `<DIV>` tag and will work like a charm!